# current_user_can with custom role and capanbility always false

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-capabilities

I've created a custom role "Expert" and added a custom capability to this role: "manage_zoom_meetings".

If I try to check if the current user has the capability, the function `current_user_can('manage_zoom_meetings')` returns `false`.

I've tested this code to check if the role is maybe not existing for the function current_user_can.

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', function ( $allcaps, $caps, $args, $user ) {
   wp_die( var_export( get_role( 'expert' )->capabilities, true ) );
   return $allcaps;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 4 );
```

The output looks like this:

```
array ( 'level_0' => true, 'manage_zoom_meetings' => true, 'read' => true, )
```

I don't understand what is wrong here.

The problem is, that I'm not able to add this capability to an admin menu item (`add_menu_page()`) or to a custom post type.

Comment: Where did you put `current_user_can('manage_zoom_meetings')`?

Comment: @MosheGross currently I use this capability for the custom post type and the admin menu:

`add_menu_page( 'Zoom Meetings', 'Zoom Meetings', 'manage_zoom_meetings', 'my-zoom-meetings', null, MY_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/img/zoom.png', 7 );`

The thing is, that I don't see this menu and the CPT. I've added the new role and capability through the plugin "User Role Editor". I also added this capability to the administrator role, but I also can't see this menu.

Comment: Hey, you might need to pass the second parameter when calling current_user_can like so. current_user_can( 'manage_zoom_meetings', get_the_ID()). get_the_ID() might not be the right one for you. Depends on the object you want to check against.

More on meta capabilites here: https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-user-roles/#primitive-capabilities-vs-meta-capabilities

Answer (score 0):

This is how I add custom roles and custom caps via `function.php` using add action init...

```php
// add the expert role and capabilities on init
add_action('init', 'expert_role');
add_action('init', 'expert_role_caps', 11);

/**
 * create expert role
 * @return void
 */
function expert_role() {

    // add role function
    add_role(
        'expert',
        'Expert',
        [
            'read' => true
        ]
    );

}

/**
 * expert role meta capabilities vars
 * @var $expert_caps array
 */
$expert_caps = [
    'level_0',
    'manage_zoom_meetings'
];

/**
 * assign expert role capabilities
 * @param $expert_caps array
 * @return void
 */
function expert_role_caps($expert_caps) {

    // gets the expert role object
    $role = get_role('expert');

    // add a custom capability
    foreach ($expert_caps as $cap) {
        $role->add_cap($cap, true);
    }

}
```

Doing this should in theory make the below code return `true` when used anywhere on your site if their current user role is expert or if the current user has this capability...

```php
var_dump(current_user_can('manage_zoom_meetings'));
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you @joshmoto!
I think you need to add the following line to the function expert_role_caps(), otherwise it won't work: `global $expert_caps`

Sadly this doen't fix the problem. I tried it with this code and the returned value is false:

`add_action( 'admin_menu', function () {
        wp_die( var_export( current_user_can( 'manage_zoom_meetings' ), true ) );
    } );`

Comment: @mcswizz Ooops sorry my bad... I forgot to add `$expert_caps` array as a parameter to the `expert_role_caps()` function. I've updated code in my answer so you don't need to set `$expert_caps` as a global variable... just simply pass it through the function as a parameter 